# When my quad draws in OpenGl, the texture stretches oddly, i need it to morph to the shape of the quad uniformly, not as shown below. How do I do so?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

[image]

This is produced by:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(pa, (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - (ha / 2));
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(pb, (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - (hb / 2));
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(pb, (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) + (hb / 2));
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(pa, (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) + (ha / 2));
glEnd();
```

And my texture parameters are as follows:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: *"[...] quad draws in OpenGl, the texture stretches oddly, i need it to [...]"* yes of course, because the quad is triangulated. What you actually do is to draw 2 triangles.

Comment: @Rabbid76 so how would I change my code such that it will give a correct looking stretch?